# A better solution for generating random numbers till it reaches a certain sum

Tags: java, random

I have an array of Random numbers and I want to keep changing the array values until it reaches a certain average which I am checking in a loop.

partial code:

numbers[] is an integer array and numbers Random[] is a Random array

```
while(avg!=avg(numbers)){
   for(...){
     numbers[i] = numbersRandom[i].nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, but that is very slow. Better to calculate the last value(s) so you have the sum you need. This can be much faster. btw it's faster to calculate the sum, rather than the average and it achieves the same result.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I take the random array and just change the last number or two manually depending on the sum I need?

Comment: And whoever had a problem with the question at least have the courtesy to let me know what is wrong!

Comment: I don't get the question. Is your problem realizing it at all? I don't think so because you already provided a partial code that does what you want. Do you want a better solution than that? Why? - I really don't think that just Yes or No to question in the title would be a sufficient answer.

Comment: @user4655509 yes, you could use recursion and back tracking. Also the max and min values need to be adjusted based on the target sum.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Could you help me with the recursive code?? The max and min values cannot be changed.

Comment: @user4655509 the actual values no, but you can calculate the max/min a value  can be based on the sum you have so far.

Comment: Without **much more** information about constraints or desired statistics, there is no real help here! Most strategies will add some bias. And no one knows what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Fill the array with the average you want: {1.5, 1.5, ... 1.5}.
2. Pick a random value.
3. Add this random value to a randomly chosen element of the array; subtract the same random value from a different randomly chosen element of the array.
4. If the whole array is not sufficiently random go back to 2.  Otherwise stop.

This method keeps the array average the same through each repetition.  In step 4 you could check the standard deviation perhaps.